# ASP.NET MVC genric list in viewdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, generics

I have generic list property which I am binding to the View. The problem is when I post the data after entering some values in view, the page get refreshed and it doesn't retain the value in the View. And also when i try to add `Html.ValidationMessage` For that particular field I get an error

```
 "The value 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<name of the class>]' is invalid"
```

My code looks like this,
**model**

```
  public List<Chart> Charts 
  { 
     get 
       { 
         return  _repository.GetCharts(Convert.ToInt32(this.Template_Id)); 
      } 
      set{} 
   }
```

**actual class**

```
 public class Chart
   {
        public string ChartDisplayText { get; set; }
   }
```

the property in Chart class is the one where I am entering the value in View
Any help much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understood it correctly but looks like your new value is not being persisted to wherever you are loading the data from in the _repository.GetCharts method.

Answer (score 0):

To retain the value after post you can return the data back like: `return View(chartList);`

the error you are getting for Validation is because in MVC validation cascading is not applied if its `Object` property. you need to apply template or use scaffolding HTML Helpers:

```
@foreach(Charts item in Model)
{
@Html.EditorFor(x => item.ChartDisplayText)
}
```

You can check for proper Scaffolding / template HTML Helpers in asp.net mvc

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for the reply. But my problem is whenever return  _repository.GetCharts(Convert.ToInt32(this.Template_Id)); executes it alwasy returns a new list of charts. Let say i have modelstate error in someother field i want to retain the value what the user entered for ChartDisplaytext during the post back. But it always creates a new one. this is the code i have written when the model state is invalid  return RedirectToAction("<action name>", "controller name", model); while the view is getting refreshed the model does not contain the user entered value